# How to create a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What should I add to my `routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
   ?
  end
end
```

to get the following route?

```
admin_user_archivals PATCH  /admin/users/:user_id/archivals(.:format)
admin/users/archivals#create
```

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match
This should help.

Comment: The issue I have is I'd like to have the controller inside the `admin/users` folder but not having the `user_archivals` key in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :admin do
 patch 'users/:user_id/archivals', to: 'controller_name#action_name', as: 'user_archivals'
end
```